# Django - How to assign AuthUser id(PK) to username?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-users

I want to assign the `id` generated to the `username` column of AuthUser Model. How can I do that?

I tried updating the `UserManager` but to no luck. Here's what I did.

```
def _create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None,
                 **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a user with the given email, and password.
    """
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    if not username:
        username = user.id  # it always returns None.

    user.username = self.model.normalize_username(username)

    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What about trying something like [Django post_save Signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#post-save)

Comment: Nope. Django requires `username` as a mandatory field. I wont be able to `save`, leave aside `post_save`.

Comment: If I'm not wrong, `user.id` will be `None` until a DB row is created

Comment: Which means `not username` will be always `True` ?

Comment: why not assign `username` after `user.save(using=self._db)`, so you can get the `id` of the user object, and saving it again.

Comment: @Bijoy - Kindly see my comment.

Comment: ya just give any random value, it will change after saving, so a static value would also work as placeholder

Comment: Random, but 'unique'.

Comment: its going to change after you assign the id to `username`, right. So its going to be unique for every signup.

Comment: @PythonEnthusiast you should create a custom user, if you did, consider posting it here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your objective. You need to start by instantiating an instance of a user with their information (email,username,password, etc...) to create the user and then save the user so they're in the DB. Once the user has been saved you can then get that users object and reassign the username to the id: 
    user = User.objects.get(username = username)
    user.username = user.id
I believe you're getting none because the user doesn't exist and has therefor there is no user to object to get an id from.Debug and confirm this line has a user object in it `user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)`

Comment: I noticed on the other comments comments about the required username but you're saving without it. Bijoy's solution of a random user is acceptable since you change it right away, additionally have you attempted an empty string? https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tips/2016/07/25/django-tip-8-blank-or-null.html

Answer (score 0):

As I stated in comments, what I proposed was to give the `username` a dummy value for saving the model for the moment, then change the value after saving

```
def _create_user(self, username=None, email=None, password=None,
                 **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a user with the given email, and password.
    """
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.username = self.model.normalize_username('placeholder')
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)

    user.username = '{}'.format(user.id)  # As the 'id' will always be unique
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user
```

The `username` with value `'placeholder'`, would change every time to the value of `id`, so there wont be issue regarding uniqueness of username.

Answer (score -1):

You need to save the user to the database by calling `user.save` - the `id` generated by the db while saving will then become available on the `user` instance.

Comment: Correct, but Django requires username as a mandatory field. How do I save it?